# AWS Feature based licensing

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-tenant, saas, rbac

I am designing a product which would be deployed to AWS.  It will use `Cognito` for user authentication. It will be a multi-tenant application.

The application has many modules/features.  The pricing depends on the features selected by the client.

Please provide guidance on how can I implement a check if the feature is licensed or not. I don't want to put the logic inside each web api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an **application microservice** (callable via a API, but with access locked down to your own application) that receives information such as:

- Authenticated User ID
- Service wanting to be accessed
- Resource-level information in case you want fine-grained access control

The **authentication microservice** would consult a database, apply appropriate business logic and return a success indicator.

Preferably:

- Each request should be logged in an **audit trail**
- If access is denied, return an **error message** that could hint at the reason why (eg 'This feature is requires subscription to the XYZ module')
- Use some form of **cache** to make the queries super-fast (eg DAX for DynamoDB, or ElastiCache)

Licensing systems can often be more complex than actual applications!